# Ubuntu Gnome: Custom Keyboard Shortcut for "gnome-screenshot -a(--area)" not working right

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, 14.10

I put this command in terminal and it works fine, allows me to select an area and all, but when I assign a shortcut to this command, I have to spam the keys for few seconds before it actually works, and this isn't a problem with the keys, as I've assigned other screenshot commands to "Shift+Print" and have tried assigning this command to other keys, and i have the same issue... I even tried making a shell script with the command and placed it in my home's bin folder and assigned a shortcut to that, and same issue, but when I run the script from terminal, it works fine.

Also, the default shortcut (the built-in one) works fine, except I can't change the save-directory, so I needed to make my own, so I don't understand where these issues come from.

EDIT: Every time I try the shortcut, it gives me a sort of noise feedback, a soft"boop" which doesn't occur with any of the other shortcuts

[image]

As you can see, these directly save the screenshot to Pictures, but I'd rather them be saved in a sub-folder in Pictures called 'screenshots' In 'dconf' I have the default save folder for screenshots set to the subfolder, but these specific built-in shortcuts ignore that and save in 'Pictures'

[image]

So I had to create custom shortcuts (as recommended on another question) These are the custom shortcuts I added, with the commands being very simple, each one works except this one(photo below), which runs fine in the terminal, except I have to spam the shortcut keys, regardless of what keys I choose, in order for it to work. This is unfortunately the one I use most..

[image]

Comment: For me,  the default shortcut (shift+PrtScn) works perfectly and I can also see the window to select the save location. Where do you get the problem exactly?

Comment: What Ubuntu do you have? I have Gnome.. are you running Ubuntu with Unity?

Comment: I added a couple photos, just give me a min

Comment: @RegisteredUser  If you have Gnome and you have settings that allow that, I would really appreciate you letting me know :)

Comment: I'm running unity btw. Sorry, I have no Idea about gnome variant.